# NLTK polarity_scores

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I was wonder if i can get the Sentimentia.polarity_scores() function to print only the negative, positive only and I can get rid of the neutral  and compound results

```
    i = 0
    while i < len(Replaced_Data):
        Sentimentia = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
        print(Sentimentia.polarity_scores(data['Clean_TweetText'][i]))
        i = i + 1

output >>> {'neg': 0.214, 'neu': 0.534, 'pos': 0.252, 'compound': 0.25}

desired output >>> {'neg': 0.214, 'pos': 0.188}
```

Comment: you can try `ss = Sentimentia.polarity_scores(data['Clean_TweetText'][i])
    print({e:ss[e] for e in ss if e in ['neg','pos']})`

Comment: @simpleApp you mind adding this as an answer so I can verify it ? that would make it easier for more people to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can filter the 'neg' and 'pos' from the dictionary using [Dictionary Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

```
ss = Sentimentia.polarity_scores(data['Clean_TweetText'][i])     
print({e:ss[e] for e in ss if e in ['neg','pos']})
```